# interpolate a variable inside of a comment

Tags: express, pug

I a trying to write the value of a loop variable inside an html comment, but I only get the raw text in my comment.

Inside a template:

```
div This is a simple div
- for itervalue in names
    label
        //This is a html comment for item #{itervalue} sent to client
        input(type='radio', name='item_name', value=itervalue)
        span item : #{itervalue}
    br
```

Result for the comment line:

```
<!--This is a html comment for item #{itervalue} sent to client-->
```

Is it possible to interpolate strings inside of a jade/pug comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HTML comments:

`<!-- This is a html comment for item #{itervalue} sent to client -->`

Comment: So simple :-) Thanks!